# PyCharm seems to install but won't run

Tags: macbook-pro, snow-leopard

This is my first OS X experience so I'm not sure what to do other than ask you guys. I can get [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/) to install, or so it seems, but when I try to run it all that happens is:

1. the icon shows up on the dock
2. a window pops up and asks me if I want to run it, I confirm
3. and then the icon disappears. It just shrinks away.

I've searched for this but I can't find anyone talking about this problem.
Once the icon goes away, nothing else happens.
I'm on a MacBook running Snow Leopard 10.6.8

This is the output from console after running Pycharm.

```
2/7/16 10:55:32 AM  pycharm[374]    Value of PYCHARM_JDK: (null)
2/7/16 10:55:32 AM  pycharm[374]    fullFileName is: /Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/bin/pycharm.vmoptions
2/7/16 10:55:32 AM  pycharm[374]    fullFileName exists: /Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/bin/pycharm.vmoptions
2/7/16 10:55:32 AM  pycharm[374]    Value of PYCHARM_VM_OPTIONS is (null)
2/7/16 10:55:32 AM  pycharm[374]    Processing VMOptions file at /Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/bin/pycharm.vmoptions
2/7/16 10:55:32 AM  pycharm[374]    Done
2/7/16 10:55:33 AM  [0x0-0x3b03b].com.jetbrains.pycharm[374]    /Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/bin/idea.properties: 'java.endorsed.dirs' already defined
2/7/16 10:55:34 AM  [0x0-0x3b03b].com.jetbrains.pycharm[374]    Start Failed: Internal error. Please report to http://jb.gg/ide/critical-startup-errors
2/7/16 10:55:34 AM  [0x0-0x3b03b].com.jetbrains.pycharm[374]    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2/7/16 10:55:34 AM  [0x0-0x3b03b].com.jetbrains.pycharm[374]        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2/7/16 10:55:34 AM  [0x0-0x3b03b].com.jetbrains.pycharm[374]        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2/7/16 10:55:34 AM  [0x0-0x3b03b].com.jetbrains.pycharm[374]        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2/7/16 10:55:34 AM  [0x0-0x3b03b].com.jetbrains.pycharm[374]        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
2/7/16 10:55:34 AM  [0x0-0x3b03b].com.jetbrains.pycharm[374]        at com.intellij.ide.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:39)
2/7/16 10:55:34 AM  [0x0-0x3b03b].com.jetbrains.pycharm[374]        at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:91)
2/7/16 10:55:34 AM  [0x0-0x3b03b].com.jetbrains.pycharm[374]    Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libawt_lwawt.dylib: dlopen(/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libawt_lwawt.dylib, 1): Symbol not found: _JNFRunLoopDidStartNotification
2/7/16 10:55:34 AM  [0x0-0x3b03b].com.jetbrains.pycharm[374]      Referenced from: /Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/./libosxapp.dylib
2/7/16 10:55:34 AM  [0x0-0x3b03b].com.jetbrains.pycharm[374]      Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/JavaNativeFoundation.framework/Versions/A/JavaNativeFoundation
2/7/16 10:55:34 AM  [0x0-0x3b03b].com.jetbrains.pycharm[374]     in /Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/./libosxapp.dylib
2/7/16 10:55:34 AM  [0x0-0x3b03b].com.jetbrains.pycharm[374]        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
2/7/16 10:55:34 AM  [0x0-0x3b03b].com.jetbrains.pycharm[374]        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1938)
2/7/16 10:55:34 AM  [0x0-0x3b03b].com.jetbrains.pycharm[374]        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1821)
2/7/16 10:55:34 AM  [0x0-0x3b03b].com.jetbrains.pycharm[374]        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
2/7/16 10:55:34 AM  [0x0-0x3b03b].com.jetbrains.pycharm[374]        at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
2/7/16 10:55:34 AM  [0x0-0x3b03b].com.jetbrains.pycharm[374]        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
2/7/16 10:55:34 AM  [0x0-0x3b03b].com.jetbrains.pycharm[374]        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1938)
2/7/16 10:55:34 AM  [0x0-0x3b03b].com.jetbrains.pycharm[374]        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1842)
2/7/16 10:55:34 AM  [0x0-0x3b03b].com.jetbrains.pycharm[374]        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
2/7/16 10:55:34 AM  [0x0-0x3b03b].com.jetbrains.pycharm[374]        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
2/7/16 10:55:34 AM  [0x0-0x3b03b].com.jetbrains.pycharm[374]        at java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Toolkit.java:1636)
2/7/16 10:55:34 AM  [0x0-0x3b03b].com.jetbrains.pycharm[374]        at java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Toolkit.java:1634)
2/7/16 10:55:34 AM  [0x0-0x3b03b].com.jetbrains.pycharm[374]        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
2/7/16 10:55:34 AM  [0x0-0x3b03b].com.jetbrains.pycharm[374]        at java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1633)
2/7/16 10:55:34 AM  [0x0-0x3b03b].com.jetbrains.pycharm[374]        at java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1668)
2/7/16 10:55:34 AM  [0x0-0x3b03b].com.jetbrains.pycharm[374]        at java.awt.Cursor.<clinit>(Cursor.java:195)
2/7/16 10:55:34 AM  [0x0-0x3b03b].com.jetbrains.pycharm[374]        at javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit.<clinit>(HTMLEditorKit.java:623)
2/7/16 10:55:34 AM  [0x0-0x3b03b].com.jetbrains.pycharm[374]        at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.<clinit>(UIUtil.java:97)
2/7/16 10:55:34 AM  [0x0-0x3b03b].com.jetbrains.pycharm[374]        at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.start(PluginManager.java:70)
2/7/16 10:55:34 AM  [0x0-0x3b03b].com.jetbrains.pycharm[374]        ... 6 more
2/7/16 10:55:34 AM  [0x0-0x3b03b].com.jetbrains.pycharm[374]    Also, an UI exception occurred on attempt to show above message:
2/7/16 10:55:34 AM  [0x0-0x3b03b].com.jetbrains.pycharm[374]    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.awt.Toolkit
2/7/16 10:55:34 AM  [0x0-0x3b03b].com.jetbrains.pycharm[374]        at java.awt.Component.<clinit>(Component.java:593)
2/7/16 10:55:34 AM  [0x0-0x3b03b].com.jetbrains.pycharm[374]        at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:316)
2/7/16 10:55:34 AM  [0x0-0x3b03b].com.jetbrains.pycharm[374]        at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:292)
2/7/16 10:55:34 AM  [0x0-0x3b03b].com.jetbrains.pycharm[374]        at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:94)
2/7/16 10:55:34 AM  com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[86]   ([0x0-0x3b03b].com.jetbrains.pycharm[374]) Exited with exit code: 3
```

Comment: Did you try to completely remove it and then install back?

Comment: Yessir, multiple times. I've tried both the community and professional editions. I also tried running from the .drag screen but it did the same exact thing as if I had dropped it in my apps folder.

Comment: Check what Console says. Application -> Utilities -> Console. Run it and try to start PyCharm again.

Comment: Done, sir. Edited results into the post.

Comment: Try to re-install Java. For your version of OS you can download it from here: https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1573?locale=en_US

Comment: Alright, I uninstalled Java and deleted Pycharm. Then I reinstalled the Java you linked me, re-booted, and then added Pycharm to my apps. It's still not running but it's doing something different. Here's the console output in a pastebin. http://pastebin.com/24sSRZtB

Comment: Here is the entire crash report. http://pastebin.com/NwuYJLKM

Comment: Well, I am afraid this will require more deep expertise than I have. May I suggest that you contact PyCharm support for this? https://www.jetbrains.com/support/

Comment: Alright (: thank you for your help though!

Comment: As the first error is "Start Failed: Internal error. Please report to http://jb.gg/ide/critical-startup-errors" then all you can do is report to Jetbrains support

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem, just so you'll know you're not alone. The only solution I found was to invoke pyCharm from the command line, although it then comes up some functionality lacking.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions